# WPF Grid Resize Unexpectedly

Tags: wpf

My project used `Grid` panel extensively for its auto-size feature. Here's how the  [MainWindow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vJO29.png) looks like. Now everything looks normal, but the moment i click the top edge of the window (resize) the `Grid` suddenly resize on its own, despite i haven't drag the cursor yet. [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J53Bz.png) was how it looks like.

If i drag the window to full-maximize, then the `Grid` size return to what it was on application start (first image). Why it behaves this way?

Comment: plz provide sample of your code